# Total number with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can total the number of characters between the `p` tags with jQuery?

I try as:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TPFkF/)**

html:

```
<b>1</b>
<b>1</b>
<b>1</b>
```

js:

```
var tBytes = 0,
    tFiles = $('b').length;
for (var tFileId = 0; tFileId < tFiles; tFileId++) {
    tBytes += $('b').text();
}
alert(tBytes);​ // Output is : 0111111111 I want output as: 3
```

What do i do?

​

Comment: Use `parseInt` or `+=+`, and don't use the whole `$('b')` collection.

Comment: If you want the total number of characters, then just do `$('b').text().length`

Comment: What about the answer? I think nobody even had a look at mine. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('b').each(function(){
total += parseInt($(this).text());
})
```

Comment: Always specify your radix, though: `total += parseInt($(this).text(), 10);`

Answer (score 2):

```
var total = 0
$('b').each(function(index, element) {
    total += $(element).text().length;
})
alert(total);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TPFkF/2/

Comment: Well, the question does say the total number of characters, so +1, but you don't need the `.each()` for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
var tBytes = 0,
    tFiles = $('b').length;
$('b').each(function(){
    tBytes += parseInt($(this).text(),10);
});
console.log(tBytes);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/TPFkF/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in pure javascript quite easily too, no need of jquery:

```
var tBytes  = 0,
    tFiles= document.getElementsByTagName('b');

for(var i=0,z=tFiles.length;i<z;i++) { 
    tBytes += +(tFiles[i].textContent || tFiles[i].innerText);
}

alert(tBytes);​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at this code:

```
Array.prototype.Sum = function()
{
    var result = 0;

    $(this).each(
        function()
        {
             result += this;
        }
    );

    return result;
};

alert($("b").map(function () { return parseInt($(this).text()); }).toArray().Sum());
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/TPFkF/8/)

Or even this one if you are interested:

```
$.fn.Sum = function()
{
    var result = 0;

    $(this).each(
        function()
        {
             result += this;
        }
    );

    return result;
};

alert($("b").map(function () { return parseInt($(this).text()); }).Sum());
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/TPFkF/10/)

And finally my favourite here:

```
$.fn.Sum = function(action)
{
    var result = 0;

    $(this).each(
        function()
        {
             result += action.call(this);
        }
    );

    return result;
};

alert($("b").Sum(function () { return parseInt($(this).text()); }));
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/TPFkF/12/)